# Access instance of UI element in view model in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

In my xaml page i am using an image control

```
<Image x:Name="MyImage" Grid.Row="1" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding SourceImage}"/>
```

like this. My question is. Is it possible to  access this control's properties in my view model. "Like MyImage.Source =". If yes, how i can achieve similar implementation in windows phone.

Comment: Do you mean that changes are immediately displayed in the UI? How about interface INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you should not. The whole purpose of the ViewModel is to separate the logic into its own class rather than having it intermixed with view code.

Instead use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to notify the UI that the image source has changed. If possible try to see if you can use a regular binding for the value you want to use, that will be the most robust and most easy way.

Another solution is to expose a interface on the view. Something like `IView`, you can probably come up with a more suitable name like `IResetable`.

```cs
interface IResetable
{
    void Reset();
}
class MainWindow: Window, IResetable
{
    publiv void Reset()
    {
        // Here you can access the view, but try to keep logic minimal.
    }
}    
class ViewModel
{
    private readonly IResetable resetable;
    public ViewModel(IResetable resetable)
    {
         _resetable = resetable;
    }
    void Foobar()        
    {
         _resetable.Reset();
    }

}
```

Comment: That i know, But my requirement is something strange. Like, In my app i am applying a render transform to an image through a behavior. So during the time of rotation i need to reset all these values; So i am searching for a provision to do that through view model.